# Why does the position of div change when there's content in it?

Tags: html, css

I want to have three divs on the same height and fill them with content. When I try to add a p-tag in the first div it is not aligned on the same height as the others:

```css
#toDo,
#getBack,
#done {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="toDo">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
<div id="getBack">
</div>
<div id="done">
</div>
```

The result should look like this:
[image]

so that every div is on the same height.

How can I prevent it that the divs get an offset from top when they get filled with content?
I already tried setting top=0; but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without adding other elements, you can just put `vertical-align: top;` to your CSS that also preserves the white space between the `div`s

```css
#toDo,
#getBack,
#done {
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="toDo">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
<div id="getBack">
</div>
<div id="done">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add display: flex to the parent container

```css
#wrapper {display: flex}
#toDo,
#getBack,
#done {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="toDo">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
<div id="getBack">
</div>
<div id="done">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vertical-align:top;` to align all inline-block div

```
#toDo, #getBack, #done{
vertical-align:top;
}
```